# AWS StepFunction CDK resultpath set to null

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-step-functions

I am not able to find a way to specify 'null' to result path.

As pointed out here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-resultpath.html

I want to implement, in CDK, this: "Discard the Result and Keep the Original Input"

I have read this discussion:
https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/1805

but there is no final answer although it has been closed.
Below a code snip:

```
const verifyDeviceJob = new tasks.LambdaInvoke(this, 'VerifyDeviceJobTask', {
      lambdaFunction: verifyConditionDeviceFn,
      inputPath: '$.detail',      
      resultPath: //HOW TO DECLARE IT TO NULL??
});
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You use special value `DISCARD` https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-stepfunctions.JsonPath.html#static-discard

So the snip would be like

```js
const verifyDeviceJob = new tasks.LambdaInvoke(this, 'VerifyDeviceJobTask', {
      lambdaFunction: verifyConditionDeviceFn,
      inputPath: '$.detail',      
      resultPath: JsonPath.DISCARD
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much , I was very confused by the DISCARD vs null.

Comment: @MarcoSinigaglia if the answer was helpful to you please consider to accept it.