# AWS CloudFormation for State machine definition: null is not allowed

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation

The AWS CloudFormation [supports YAML for state machine defintion](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/03/aws-step-functions-adds-tooling-support-for-yaml/), but my CloudFormation cannot deployed if it contains `null` values in YAML documents.

On the other hand, the `ResultPath` must be `null` [to discard the result and keep the original input for any state](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/03/aws-step-functions-adds-tooling-support-for-yaml/).

Is there any way that I can use YAML for AWS CloudFormation while using `null` values in the YAML document?

p.s. I found [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66050056/1479078) but this is about [CDK](https://aws.amazon.com/cdk/) not [CloudFormation](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/).

Comment: Can you share the cloudformation template you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

Found 2 options:
"ResultPath": {"Ref" : "AWS::NoValue"}
or
"ResultPath": "NULL",